# PHP date showing '1970-01-01 ' after conversion

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I have a form in which date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` . For searching database , I hanverted the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` . But when I `echo` it, it showing `1970-01-01` . The PHP code is below:

```
$date1 = $_REQUEST['date'];     
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

Why is it happening? How can I format it to `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: because its 0000-00-00 in your db

Comment: its not coming from db, its from my `html page` to `php`

Comment: The strtotime input is wrong. Check the $date1.

Comment: @AssamGuy - The format `dd/mm/yyyy` should be `dd-mm-yyyy` so you will need to replace your `/` characters.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Replace `/` with `-`:

```
$date1 = strtr($_REQUEST['date'], '/', '-');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

Comment: Simple and effective @Cyclone!

Comment: I had this probem when coverting two UK dates to MySQL format. Your help is very much appreciated. Works like a dream!

Comment: I do the same but problem is still can you help @Cyclonecode

Comment: @ankitsuthar - Very hard to give a solution without seeing the date you're trying to format. Try removing any whitespaces from the string before using `strtotime()`?

Answer (score 36):

January 1, 1970 is the so called Unix epoch. It's the date where they started counting the [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). If you get this date as a return value, it usually means that the conversion of your date to the Unix timestamp returned a (near-) zero result. So the date conversion doesn't succeed. Most likely because it receives a wrong input.

In other words, your `strtotime($date1)` returns 0, meaning that `$date1` is passed in an unsupported format for the strtotime function.

Comment: Thus, putting a condition like`if (strtotime($date1))` before the conversion seems like a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$inputDate = '07/05/-0001';
$dateStrVal = strtotime($inputDate);
if(empty($dateStrVal))
{
  echo 'Given date is wrong'; 
}
else{
 echo 'Date is correct';
}
```

O/P : Given date is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = $_REQUEST['date'];

if($date1) {
    $date1 = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
} else {
    $date1 = '';
}
```

This will display properly when there is a valid `date()` in `$date` and display nothing if not.
Solved the issue for me.

Comment: I've used this with PHPExcel and it works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

Convert datepicker `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
$startDate = trim($_POST['startDate']);
$startDateArray = explode('/',$startDate);
$mysqlStartDate = $startDateArray[2]."-".$startDateArray[1]."-".$startDateArray[0];
$startDate = $mysqlStartDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when your data is set to 000-00-00 or empty you must double-check and give the correct information and this issue will go away. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

**Use below code for php 5.3+:**

```
$date = new DateTime('1900-02-15');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Use below code for php 5.2:**

```
$date = new DateTime('1900-02-15');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between those two

Answer (score -2):

finally i have found a one line code to solve this problem

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT'])));
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this, you picked code from everyone else and put it on one line? Have you ever heard about code readability?