# Result inserting in mysql database in UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I have a strange problem . I am trying to insert some values to database with respective date . In HTML form, the date format is mm/dd/yyyy format. I converted this format to mysql `yyyy-mm-dd` format using the following PHP [(from stackoverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984595/php-date-showing-1970-01-01-after-conversion):

```
echo $date1 = str_replace("/","-",$_POST['date']);
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

But the above echo , when I run the code it shows like this:
`07-30-2012 1970-01-01`

Comment: The answer you link to converts `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`, and that is different from `mm/dd/yyyy` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $date = preg_replace('/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})$/', '$3-$1-$2', $_POST['date']);
```

I think this code should work fine, but of course you must do all necessary checks before insert it into database.

Comment: Thanks CyberDemon...its working. Can you explain or just give a help link,I will b grtful to u

Comment: I had used regular expression to modify string (reorder numbers and replace slash to dash).

Answer (score 3):

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php for details.

So even you are passing '07-30-2012' as an input, it is considering 07 as date, 30 as month hence you are getting incorrect results.

Following should work

```
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $date1 = str_replace("/","-","$_POST['date']");
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

put double quotes in date then you get perfect result

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried :

```
$date = "30/07/2012";
echo $date1 = str_replace("/","-",$date);
echo '<br />';
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

And it's actually returning :

```
30-07-2012
2012-07-30
```

You should check your $_POST['date'] format.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));`

Your first line is incorrect, which returns false, which (converted to an integer) is 0, 0 is the beginning of time on a linux machine! (hence 1970-01-01)

Answer (score 0):

Your input is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, that means you should use slashes `/` You would need to change to dashes if you were using `dd-mm-yyyy` format, as is shown in the answer you link to. So in your case you should not replace the `/`.