# cant change date format posted in form in PHP from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, sql, date

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions is working for me, I have got a form in which the user enters the date of birth, but for reason it is set to `mm/dd/yyyy` and I want to change it to `dd/mm/yyyy`. As soon as i enter the date like 19/12/1992 it prompts invalid date format.

The code in the form is :

```
<label for="name">Date of Birth (mm/dd/yyyy) <font color="red"> *</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="DOB" value="<?php echo $info['DOB']; ?>" onfocus="$(this).removeClass('date required')" onchange="$(this).addClass('date required')" required />
```

And the code in the function after POST is:

```
$DOB = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DOB']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like they all said do this

```
 $DOB = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DOB']);
 $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($DOB));
```

Then at the other side where you are either inserting or updating the database change the date back to mysql standard format like this:

```
$DOB_DB = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DOB']);
$DOB_DB = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($DOB_DB));
```

Comment: It worked this way by reverting the format back, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** use this:

1)

```
 $DOB = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DOB']);
           $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($DOB));
```

OR

2) `$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $DOB)->format('d/m/Y');`

Comment: thanks a lot, but now it is not saving the value, it is saving a date 01/01/1970

Comment: @user3297381 see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984595/php-date-showing-1970-01-01-after-conversion

Comment: may be the format you are trying to conver is unsuported by strtotime.

Comment: @user3297381 can you try the second option and see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strtotime`:

```
$oldDOB = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DOB']);
$DOB = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($oldDOB));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but now it is not saving the value, it is saving a date 01/01/1970